# What is Dagger? And why we use it?

Tags: android

How to use Dagger in my Android project and what is the main purpose of using it? I searched it on google but I am not clear about it.So please give me the best solution and an example also if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately your question is to broad to be a good fit for our community. I suggest that you read the Dagger documentation and learn more about Android development in general.

Comment: If you are new to Android don't use Dagger yet, unless its clear to you on what are the real world problems that needs to be addressed.

Comment: I hate Dagger2 with all my energy. It is for lazy people (:

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Many Android apps rely on instantiating objects that often require other dependencies. For instance, a Twitter API client may be built using a networking library such as Retrofit. To use this library, you might also need to add parsing libraries such as Gson. In addition, classes that implement authentication or caching may require accessing shared preferences or other common storage, requiring instantiating them first and creating an inherent dependency chain.

Dagger 2 analyzes these dependencies for you and generates code to help wire them together. While there are other Java dependency injection frameworks, many of them suffered limitations in relying on XML, required validating dependency issues at run-time, or incurred performance penalties during startup. Dagger 2 relies purely on using Java annotation processors and compile-time checks to analyze and verify dependencies. It is considered to be one of the most efficient dependency injection frameworks built to date.

Advantages

Here is a list of other advantages of using Dagger 2:

- Simplifies access to shared instances. Just as the ButterKnife library makes it easier to define references to Views, event handlers, and resources, Dagger 2 provides a simple way to obtain references to shared instances. For instance, once we declare in Dagger our singleton instances such as MyTwitterApiClient or SharedPreferences, we can declare fields with a simple @Inject annotation:

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     @Inject MyTwitterApiClient mTwitterApiClient;
     @Inject SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
         // assign singleton instances to fields
         InjectorClass.inject(this);
     }
  }
  ```
- Easy configuration of complex dependencies. There is an implicit order in which your objects are often created. Dagger 2 walks through the dependency graph and generates code that is both easy to understand and trace, while also saving you from writing a large amount of boilerplate code you would normally need to write by hand to obtain references and pass them to other objects as dependencies. It also helps simplify refactoring, since you can focus on what modules to build rather than focusing on the order in which they need to be created.
- Easier unit and integration testing Because the dependency graph is created for us, we can easily swap out modules that make network responses and mock out this behavior.
- Scoped instances Not only can you easily manage instances that can last the entire application lifecycle, you can also leverage Dagger 2 to define instances with shorter lifetimes (i.e. bound to a user session, activity lifecycle, etc.).

Comment: Considering the tremendous amount of time and effort that goes into configuring Dagger, I feel like your example isn't complete.